# Should django migrations be applied automatically when using docker?

Tags: python, django, docker

I'm dockerizing a Django app and I saw that some people run the migrations in the docker-compose.yml file but some people don't, what is the best solution?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If some people do and some don't, you can expect 50-50 answers :D

There are two answers why some people do not include `migrate` in `docker-compose`:

1. They have them elsewhere (some outside script, that is executed from other command).
2. They don't want things like `migrate` or `runserver` start automatically, wchich might be good practise for some cases.

Comment: thanks dude finally I created a script to automatically make the migration